# SQLite3 join and group values by date

Tags: sqlite

I have a super simple Sqlite3 db where I track what I am working on via a bash script. It's a year's worth of data in only one table. Not a SQL guy (obviously). All I want to do is group the dates by month and then sort them by the tag, to create a report. I've read a bunch of posts, googled, etc and read the documentation. I also tried a bunch of joins but I can't get it right.

Date, Time, Tag, Note

10/13/2020 15:11:27 WRK HR 300 Responsibility online course

10/13/2020 16:00:57 MTG A&SS All Team Meeting

10/13/2020 8:13:26  WRK Check email slack teams and TDX

10/13/2020 8:23:58  WRK Mock up reassignment and attributes DC sandbox

10/13/2020 8:45:48  MTG TDX Global Ops meeting

10/13/2020 9:00:20  MTG DC Support Morning Huddle

10/14/2020 08:03:31 WRK Check email TDX slack and teams

10/14/2020 08:18:24 WRK 164680 set up collector and email monitor for CUL Facilities

10/14/2020 09:01:07 MTG DC Support daily huddle

10/14/2020 10:12:05 MTG Hosting Checkin

10/14/2020 10:12:17 WRK Update TDX Daily Check notification setting and ticket app settings

10/14/2020 10:29:36 MTG iPaaS follow up with TDX folks

10/14/2020 12:26:53 VAC Half day off afternoon

10/15/2020 08:05:42 WRK Check TDX slack teams and email

10/15/2020 08:23:23 WRK 166268 for Bob survey question

10/15/2020 08:59:36 MTG Daily Check support huddle

10/15/2020 10:12:15 WRK Slack question from Michael regarding GuestIDs and DC

10/15/2020 10:20:53 WRK Ping Gabriel on 164574

10/15/2020 10:22:37 WRK Close out 163764 for Heather

10/15/2020 13:08:05 MTG Daily Check support noon huddle

10/15/2020 13:08:31 WRK Daily Check support shift from 1 to 5pm

Comment: I am trying to work through an example that is given using the sample database that you can download. The code they provide is here [SQLite Self-Join](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-self-join/) The part I don't understand is where they are getting the "m.firstname" and "e.firstname" stuff. I understand notation but I don't see what the "e" and the "m" are referencing.